# Is there a way to create a copy-on-write copy of a directory?

Tags: filesystems, hardlink

I'm thinking of a situation where I would have something that creates a copy of a directory, tweaks a few files, and then does some processing on the result. This wold be done fairly often, maybe a few dozen times a day. (The exact use case is testing patch submissions; dupe the code, patch it, build/test/report/etc.)

What I'm looking for could be done by creating a new directory structure and populating it with hard links from the origonal. However this only works if all the tools you use delete and recreate files rather than edit them in place.

*Is there a way to have the file system do [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) for a file?*

---

Note: I'm aware that many FSs use COW at a block level (all updates are done via writes to new blocks) but this is not what I want.

Comment: It doesn't appear maintained, but perhaps http://boklm.eu/copyfs/

Comment: So you want to do copy-on-write via the filesystem, but you don't want a filesystem that uses copy-on-write? I'm confused.

Comment: @Kamil Kisiel: I want file-level COW not block-level COW. File-level COW results in `cp` and `ln` doing almost exactly the same thing. Block-level COW is a trick to minimize the interval that the FS meta data is incorrect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Copy-on-write_transactional_model

Comment: What kind of system is this expected to be used on?

Comment: It's speculative enough that unless you know of a way to do it for some setup (in that case just post it) I wouldn't want people burning time figuring out how to do it (unless they are doing it for fun :)

Answer (score 9):

If you have your choice of platform for your fileserver, I'd go with a recent OpenSolaris build and use the deduplication feature of ZFS. This way copies of files would take up no additional space, and even common segments between files would not be replicated.

You can read all about ZFS deduplication at [this post on Jeff Bonwick's Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/zfs-deduplication-v2).

Comment: ZFS is amazing; it will change the way you think about storage

Comment: Neat, unless there's a down side to having it on for the whole drive.

Comment: I added a link to a blog post that has more technical details. You can see if it's what you need there.

Comment: New url for post of Jeff Bonwick: https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/zfs-deduplication-v2

Answer (score 1):

I find this question while searching a better solution instead of my current, which is like: `cp -al SOURCEDIRNAME copy.SOURCEDIRNAME` or

```
find SOURCEDIRNAME -type d -exec mkdir -p copy.{} ';'
find SOURCEDIRNAME -type f -exec ln {} copy.{} ';'
```

At this point i have a copy of the structure with a bunch of hardlinks. This works relative fast, and don't need one time more disk space, cause we do not rly copy all files. Now i can do some ''stuff'' (like `patch` or build) on the copy directory. If they do not modify the original files, only rename them and/or create new files. After the work, i have some results and can remove the copy directory and start over.

If you use more complicated tools and dont trust them (or you know they try to overwrite existing files) you may need [cowdancer](http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/cowdancer/).

Answer (score 1):

Try use one of UniouFS, AUFS or [Overlay Filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html) (depends on which supported in Your distro)

For example OverlayFS used by docker as one of drivers to merge layers

[Overlay Filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html)

> Overlaying mainly involves directories. If a given name appears in
>   both upper and lower filesystems and refers to a non-directory in
>   either, then the lower object is hidden - the name refers only to the
>   upper object.
>
> Where both upper and lower objects are directories, a merged directory
>   is formed.
>
> At mount time, the two directories given as mount options “lowerdir”
>   and “upperdir” are combined into a merged directory:
>
> ```
> mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,workdir=/work /merged
> ```
>
> The “workdir” needs to be an empty directory on the same filesystem as
>   upperdir.

Comment: Or UnionFS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS#Other_implementations. When you mount with upperdir empty, enable cow mode, then attempt to modify anything in lowerdir, the fs will create a (modified) copy in upperdir, which will then be used for subsequent accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Most [linux virtualization solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) offer file-level COW among virtualized OSes (copied from the WP):

- YES:

  - Docker, Linux-VServer, lmctfy, LXC, Singularity, Virtuozzo, Sandboxie, systemd-nspawn, Solaris Containers(ZFS), FreeBSD jail(ZFS), OpenVZ
- NO:

  - chroot, sysjail, WPARs, iCore Virtual Accounts, Turbo

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score -2):

May be SVN or other versioning tool (git, cvs)?

Comment: That's even worse because it creates two copies of each file and sucks them down over a socket.